# Database Design for evolving entities

Tags: database-design, relations

I am looking for some best practices regarding table design when an entity is expected to evolve over time and get more properties.

As an example let's consider a `process` that has a bunch of metadata and can either be running or finished. A running process would have a `startTime` but no `endTime`, whereas a finished process needs to have an `endTime`. It is assumed that every `runningProcess` will be finished at some point.

I see some general approaches:

1. A single table `processes` with a nullable `endTime` column where all processes are stored
2. Two tables `runningProcesses` and `finishedProcesses` that look the same except for the `finishedProcesses` having an `endTime` column that the `runningProcesses` table lacks.
3. An extra table `processEndTimes` that only stores a `processId` with a FK constraint and an `endTime`

Option 1) is pretty simple but has the disadvantage that a query for `finishedProcesses` would run on a larger table and filter by the `endTime` column.

Option 2) has the disadvantage that ending a process is not an atomic action any more but needs to be a transaction to delete a row from `runningProcesses` and insert a row in `finishedProcesses`. Additionally, a query for all processes with some metadata would always run on a union of the tables.

Option 3) seems to overcome the disadvantages of Option 1) and 2) but has the disadvantage that the table design does not reflect the way I'd model the processes in business logic.

What option would you go for? And why?

Answer (score 1):

## Option 4

`process` table with only process Metadata. No `start_time`/`end_time`.

`processLog` table with process ID, a `log_type` column (start, end, info, debug, error, "I'm on step X", etc)  and a few others.

`processStatus` (materialized) view of the previous two tables.

And a few `process_api` procedures to control the flow of data.

**Description**

In this design

- the **M**odel is hidden
- you look at the data through a **V**iew
- and **C**ontrol the new data via API.

[MVC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Comment: Thank you for your insights @Michael!
However, is it to be considered good practice that the model is hidden at this level?
In my actual projects, accessing a database will always  be done over an API anyway, so the model is never exposed to the user. But wouldn't I want to expose the model to other developers including myself a few months down the road to reveal the intention at first glance?